# How to use variable content in MailChimp?

Tags: html, templates, mailchimp

**My code problem**

I'm having some trouble with variant content in Mailchimp, I can't figure out how I have to code it to make it happen.
So if anynone has coded some fonctional template with variable content please exaplain me the structure or give an example code so I can figure out how it works.

I'm actually starting to think it is not available anymore because even the example code provided by MailChimp does not work!

I've copy/past the example code given by MailChimp in a basic template taken from MailChimp.(I found it here https://blog.mailchimp.com/working-with-variant-selectors/)

(I won't put the code here, it is really long)

When I say it does not work, I mean that I can edit, remove or duplicate the blocks but I do not have access to the drop-down menu that allows you to select a type of content you want add.

I know the article is like 5 years old so maybe things I've changed but this the only example I've found on the internet... 
Here you can find the only updated info about this:  http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/create-editable-content-areas-with-mailchimps-template-language#Variable-Content-Area (it is not really solid)

**Story behind:**

I'm coding an editable newsletter for the company I'm working for.

The newsletter is going to have a lot of different content in it so I thought it would be clever to use a different color of title background for each type of content.
For example the Marketing content would have a blue title backgroud, IT would be green and so on...

The thing is there is going to be something like 10 different types of content and there would be only 3 or 4 of them in one newsletter.
So I thaught it would be a bit messy to put in the template 10 blocks while only 3 or 4 of them would be actually used.

Sadly, it is impossible to duplicate a block and change its color without changing the original one.

So I thaught it would be great to code 10 different variable content so the user could pick one of them, add it and then change the color if needed.

Post update:

I have just seen that the article about MailChimp repeatable or variable content was edited 5 days ago. I guess the option is still alive they would have erased the part about variable content if it was not.

article here:http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/basic-and-themes/repeatable-or-variable-content-blocks

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just created a custom template that makes use of the variable content and after a ironing out a few issues it all worked as expected.

You need to make sure that:

- the `mc:repeatable` attribute on each element match up
- each of the repeatable elements are exactly adjacent to each other
- the `mc:edit` on each section is unique (especially if you want to change colours)

Here's some code that worked for me:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" class="contentWrapper">
        <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->

        <!-- // Begin Module: Item - no top border with image \\ -->
        <table class="bodyContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="siwc_600" mc:variant="content with left image - no top border">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/placeholder_180.gif" style="max-width:180px;" mc:label="image" mc:edit="liwc600_image00"/>
                </td>
                <td width="20"></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div mc:edit="liwc600_content00">
                        <h1><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">Content with no top border</a></h1>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquam risus ligula, at dignissim dui condimentum ac. Proin a tortor id eros molestie pretium sit amet
                        at eros. Vivamus faucibus mauris ullamcorper arcu dignissim feugiat.<br/><br/><a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="30"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // End Module: Item - no top border with image \\ -->

        <!-- // Begin Module: Item - no top border witout image  \\ -->
        <table class="bodyContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" mc:repeatable="siwc_600" mc:variant="content with no image - no top border">
            <tr>
                <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div mc:edit="riwc600_content00">
                        <h1><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">Content with no top border</a></h1>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquam risus ligula, at dignissim dui condimentum ac. Proin a tortor id eros molestie pretium sit amet
                        at eros. Vivamus faucibus mauris ullamcorper arcu dignissim feugiat. Mauris sagittis est diam, et congue erat varius vel. Integer iaculis pharetra sapien, sed varius metus
                        blandit nec.<br/><br/><a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // End Module: Item - no top border without image \\ -->

        <!-- // Begin Module: Left Image with Content \\ -->
        <table class="bodyContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
               mc:repeatable="siwc_600" mc:variant="content with left image">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="2" bgcolor="#ededed"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/placeholder_180.gif" style="max-width:180px;" mc:label="image" mc:edit="liwc600_image00"/>
                </td>
                <td width="20"></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div mc:edit="liwc600_content01">
                        <h1><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">Standard content with border</a></h1>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquam risus ligula, at dignissim dui condimentum ac. Proin a tortor id eros molestie pretium sit amet
                        at eros. Vivamus faucibus mauris ullamcorper arcu dignissim feugiat. Mauris sagittis est diam, et congue erat varius vel. Integer iaculis pharetra sapien, sed varius metus
                        blandit nec.<br/><br/><a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="30"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // End Module: Left Image with Content \\ -->

        <!-- // END BODY -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank that works well!

Actually my problem was really stupid: I did not realise the variant blocs were only available on Campaign Editor. Took me some time to realise that my script was good but was no use in the template Editor...